# NSXMLParser error code 201

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an xml data called

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <OfflineDealModel>
            <DealUri>http://www.upto75.com/Therapy_Ayurveda/m/5505/Sale_Offer.html</DealUri>
            <DealCode i:nil="true"/>
        </OfflineDealModel>
```

When I am parsing this data I am getting the error code called 201 at the line             `<DealCode i:nil="true"/>`.Kindly help me how to solve this.Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: can you add the code where you are initialising the parser?

Comment: Can you provide the full NSError description?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your tag not closed properly.

```
<DealCode i:nil="true">
</DealCode>
```

Comment: if you observe at my xml there is /at the end of deal code .That means it is ended

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

Just Try This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <OfflineDealModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DealUri>http://www.upto75.com/Therapy_Ayurveda/m/5505/Sale_Offer.html</DealUri>
        <DealCode i:nil="true" />
</OfflineDealModel>
```

may be its work